# Doctrine delete the oldest entry

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have one MongoDb document with 3 fields `message`, `author`, `sendAt`, i have created a query builder to count all DB entries on this document and if there is more than 20 entries, I'm trying to delete the oldest one.

`sendAt` is the current dateTime when the message is send (`"sendAt" : ISODate("2016-01-21T08:53:00Z")`)

I have an unfinished query builder

```
public function deleteOldestMessage()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->delete('m')
        ->from('Messages', 'm')
        ->where('m.sendAt = ')
        ->execute();
}
```

But i really don't know what i should add on the `where` condition.
I should maybe order `DESC` the `sendAt` field and delete the first on the list ?

How can I tell the query builder to delete the oldest one ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$messages = $qb->select('m')
    ->from('Messages', 'm')
    ->orderBy('m.sendAt', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
// You will receive array where in the top will be the oldest message.
if (count($messages) > 20) {
    // And in your desired case, you can remove just one oldest message.
    $messageToDelete = array_shift($messages);
    $em->remove($lastMessage);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need first to select the oldest one then you can delete it like this :

```
    $qb->select('m')
   ->from('Messages', 'm')
   ->orderBy('m.sendAt', 'DESC'); 
   $messages = $qb->getResult();
```

thene

```
    if(count($messages) >= 20){
        //get the first element of array which is the oldest one
        $lastMessage = current($messages); 
        $em->remove($lastMessage);
    }
```

Comment: What about `more than 20 entries`

Answer (score 2):

You use sql query builder options instead of mongodb.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->remove()
    ->sort('sendAt', 'asc')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult()
    ->execute();
```

Comment: What about `more than 20 entries`

Comment: You said that you have that query. First make count query, and if there is more that 20 do second query.

Comment: Yes, I call this query only if there is more than 20 entries

Comment: With your answer i get this error `Iterator would not be returned for query type: 6 `

Comment: So yes, you should use query to find latest id, and remove it later like in the answer below.